# ArcGIS Online Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis-experience-builder

I'm new to the ArcGIS Online Experience Builder.  I've finalized my experience, but the view of the landing page differs, depending on the browser and/or device type being used (see screenshots below).

For example, the box looks smaller or text within that box is cut off when using Chrome on an external monitor.

How do I ensure a consistent view across all browsers/device types (whether a laptop or desktop monitor)??

I used a blank template when building my experience, if that matters.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Experience Builder you can set the layout for 3 resolutions, namely "small, medium and large", or "phone, tablet and desktop". You'll need to build, arrange and layout for each specific layout. Clicking one of the icons will bring you into the layout mode for said resolution.
[image]

You can also set the resolution using the drop down to see how it'll display for someone. Using the drop down resolution button should match some of your screen shots. It's a matter of finding the right balance in each layout as you can only have "3" designs (small, medium, large). See the [layout help topic](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/build-apps/design-for-mobile-devices.htm) for a bit more information. Keep in mind, as you only have 3 high level or coarse resolutions, the site will never look exactly the same across every possible screen resolution.